# ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found using spring boot with hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am using spring data jpa with hibernate and oracle as database. There are two entities with many-to-many relation. There is a join table called membership between the two entities. When hibernate attempt to create an entry in the membership table we get the following error.

```
    Hibernate: update process_history set process_id=?, process_state=?, record_time=?, user_name=?, record_comment=? where id=?
Hibernate: insert into membership (process_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
2023-04-19 21:59:23.867  WARN 36164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
2023-04-19 21:59:23.867 ERROR 36164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-02291: integrity constraint (abcUser.FK40YSATSPCISFY32017BX9LM7G) violated - parent key not found

2023-04-19 21:59:23.871  INFO 36164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl
```

: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

The two entities are as follows:

```
Process.java

    public class Process{
    
     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable( name = "membership",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "process_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
        private Set<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = new HashSet<>();
    }
    
    ApplicationUser.java
    public ApplicationUser{ 
    @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applicationUsers",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set<Process> processes = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

how to overcome this error.